# Setting Buttons in Head of view

Tags: swift, macos, layout, nsbutton

I am working with an app for macOS. So I want to set six Buttons in top of view using the complete width of view. When I resize the view the buttons should resize at the same time, so the width of the buttons should raise as the view is raising in same relation
How can I do that. Is it possible using the autolayout? Or do I need to change the position (x, y) and size programmatically? But how can I change the position?
Thank you for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Programmatically, position and the size can be set by adjusting the `.frame` property of the NSView object.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483713-frame

2. Also, it could be archived with Auto Layout by setting the left and right constrains of each element (and not specifying a width constrain) so the distance between each element, and the distance from the left-most element to the view.minX and right-most element to view.maxX are fixed (while the width is calculated dynamically). Additionally, add a height constrain so the heights remain the same.

Please follow up if you need more information ;)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: To set the value programmatic it didn’t work. How I can set the position, I tried it with the method frame.insetBy, but it didn’t work

Comment: Check out this post if you are trying to set the position programmatically and it does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36732959/6426085

Comment: Also, if you are just setting the position of these items programmatically can you try to remove all the auto layout constrains and try again?